# How to generate "VSTemplate" file from a WebSite/Project (Visual Studio/.NET)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projectgen

Is there any API or command-line able to generate a VSTemplate file from a WebSite/Project that is NOT by using Projectgen.exe?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use Projectgen.exe?

Comment: Actually when I posted this question I was at work, I could'nt find the Visual Studio Tools for Applications in any of the Microsoft DVD covers I searched and also didn't get to download it at that time. But yes, If I get to put my hands on this software I can use Projectgen.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website shows a simple example of how to create your own VSTemplate file.

From this you should be able to whip up a script to do what you want if you are unable to use the Projectgen.exe tool.

http://blogs.msdn.com/craigskibo/archive/2004/06/29/168994.aspx

Comment: I'll take a look at it and eventually vote you... thanks for your reply